# Custom content for front page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is there any plugin available which I can use to post custom content on My front page?? I am using front page which has link to other blog pages. I want to put custom content on this front page but i am unable to find any plugin.

whatever plugins which i searched gives this facility for sidebar in a widget format there were no option for manually putting content in my theme.

Also is it possible to put latest post by a particular author on this page??

Comment: I got 1 plugin for latest post by author http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/latest-posts-by-author/?topic_id=9430 and it works fine now i want something for custom content now please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit index.php file in you're theme to do this . have a look at [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) , what i would recomend is having a category called home_content and limit all the theme files using query_posts not to show that category , and show posts from that category only on the homepage ( index.php file from you're theme ) .

You could allso ask wordpress related questions on [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: i edited the theme i need something on admin panel which can be used for putting content on that page

Comment: you can post articles in the specific category and it will show there if you follow my guide .